# Display (custom) post number of views

Tags: views

I'd like to display at the top of every post (actually those are custom posts) the number of times it was viewed by users.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-track-and-display-post-views-count-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/comment-page-1/#comment-8646 
but it's not well displayed with my theme's custom posts

Comment: Please explain the problem with more details, this is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a repurposed post from another question which the OP did not find useful, so I'm reposting it here and hopefully will be useful here*

Please modify the code as needed.

Here is a post I have recently done on stackoverflow. It is a modified version of the code you are using. I had the same problem with that code.

This is the code that I use to display post views in my website. Please note, admin views aren't counted, and if someone goes to the same post within 12 hours, the second view aren't counted. A second view count is only registered if that person visits the page again after 12 hours. So this is a much more accurate way of counting post views

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pietergoosen_get_post_views' ) ) :

function pietergoosen_get_post_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return 0;
   }
   return $count;
}

endif;

// function to count views.
if ( ! function_exists( 'pietergoosen_update_post_views' ) ) :

    function pietergoosen_update_post_views($postID) {
       if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
         $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //retrieve the current IP address of the visitor
         $key = $user_ip . 'x' . $postID; //combine post ID & IP to form unique key
         $value = array($user_ip, $postID); // store post ID & IP as separate values (see note)
         $visited = get_transient($key); //get transient and store in variable

         //check to see if the Post ID/IP ($key) address is currently stored as a transient
         if ( false === ( $visited ) ) {

            //store the unique key, Post ID & IP address for 12 hours if it does not exist
            set_transient( $key, $value, 60*60*12 );

           // now run post views function
           $count_key = 'post_views_count';
           $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
           if($count==''){
              $count = 0;
              delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
              add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
           }else{
              $count++;
              update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
           }
         }
       }
    }

endif;

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

You can now just simply add the following code where you need to display the count

```
<div class="readercount">
   <?php $views = pietergoosen_get_post_views(get_the_ID());
       if(pietergoosen_get_post_views(get_the_ID()) == 1) {  
          printf( __( '%d Reader have read this post.', 'pietergoosen' ) , $views );
       } else {  
          printf( __( '%d Readers have read this post.', 'pietergoosen' ) , $views );  
       }  
   ?>
</div>
```

and add the following code in single.php to register the count

```
pietergoosen_update_post_views(get_the_ID());
```